# Django - How to use the exact same clean() method on multiple forms

Tags: python, django, forms, validation, django-forms

I have multiple forms that uses the same `clean()` and `clean_<field_name>()` methods.

My problem is that i write the exact same code for all my forms, something like:

```
forms.py

class FirstForm(forms.Form):
    ...

    clean():
        <long clean code that repeats on all forms>

    clean_field1():
        <clean_field1 code that repeats on all forms>

class SecondForm(forms.Form):
    ...

    clean():
        <long  clean code that repeats on all forms>

    clean_field1():
        <clean_field1 code that repeats on all forms>

class ThirdForm(forms.Form):
    ...

    clean():
        <long  clean code that repeats on all forms>

    clean_field1():
        <clean_field1 code that repeats on all forms>
```

So my question is what it the best approach to write those `clean()` methods on 1 place and just call them on different forms?

Answer (score 2):

You *subclass*. You first make an abstract form:

```
class SomeBaseForm(forms.Form):
    # ...

    clean():
        # long clean code that repeats on all forms
        pass

    clean_field1():
        # clean_field1 code that repeats on all forms
        pass
```

and then you subclass that `SomeBaseForm` in the forms:

```
class FirstForm(SomeBaseForm):
    # ...

class SecondForm(SomeBaseForm):
    # ...

class ThirdForm(SomeBaseForm):
    # ...
```

So here the `FirstForm`, `SecondForm` and `ThirdForm` will *inherit* from the `SomeBaseForm` the `clean` and `clean_field1` method.

If you want to inherit (and change) the `Meta` class, you can do that as well. For example:

```
class SomeBaseForm(forms.Form):
    # ...

    class Meta:
        model = SomeModel
        fields = ['name']
```

and then we can subclass like:

```
class FirstForm(SomeBaseForm):
    # ...

    class Meta(SomeBaseForm.Meta):
        fields = ['name', 'description']
```

Comment: Thanks Willem! sounds good. I just wonder - could this `SomeBaseForm` only contain the clean methods and nothing else (no Meta class, no fields, no __init__) ?

Comment: @shayms8: you can add all kinds of elements, like `__init__`, etc. As long as it inherit. For `Meta`, you can inherit the meta class of the parent.

Comment: I'll try to be more clear. I want that `SomeBaseForm` will contain ONLY clean methods and nothing else. This could work ?  BTW - can you please write an example of how i can call the `SomeBaseForm.clean() ` on `FirstForm` for example ?

Comment: @shayms8: just `my_firstform.clean()`. Subclassing is nothing special. If you call a method, and it is not in that class, it moves up the hierarchy (MRO), until it finds one such method.